# How can I detect event leaks in jQuery or enumerate the objects in jQuery's cache?

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks

We seem to keep accidentally introducing memory leaks into our application because we are adding event handlers to elements and forgetting to remove them when the parent element is being removed from the DOM. I realize it's a silly error, and it's pretty easy to fix once we discover it, but I'd like to automate the discovery of this error in code.

Originally, I thought I would periodically enumerate the objects in the internal jQuery cache and count the event listeners for each of the objects in the cache, to look for counts that are increasing and never decreasing. That generally indicates that we're adding event handlers that we're not removing. I also considered enumerating the objects in the cache to find all of the elements that are no longer in the DOM, as this older code shows: https://gist.github.com/RubaXa/5057568
That would indicate that the object still has an event listener attached, even though it's orphaned.

However, access to $.cache  is no longer possible with jQuery, making these sorts of leak detections difficult. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: You don't need to remove event handlers when the element is removed, it will be done automatically.

Comment: @Barmar, there appears to be an internal jQuery cache that remembers all event listeners that were ever added to each element. If the element is removed in a way that jQuery isn't aware of, the item, and its event handlers, stay in this internal cache and are thus never GC'd. If that handler function happens to be a closure that references large objects in its scope, we have found that we leak memory unexpectedly because we are still referring to objects we didn't intend to.

Comment: Why are you removing elements in ways that jQuery isn't aware of? Are you doing it so much that the leakage is a real problem? Maybe you should fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google chrome profiler to find memory leaks in your app. Use google chrome browser to navigate to your page. Open up the inspector by right click and inspect, then go to profiles and choose Record Allocation Timeline. You will see a graph with memory usage. Start navigating your page and as you surf your page your memory will go up and down, if for some reason the memory stays up even after leaving the area that caused it to spike, then it means that area has a memory leak. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9DK2.png)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that's actually how we're detecting these leaks now. I'm trying to automate the detection in code though since I know what mistake we're making.